# What does it mean when a Hasse diagram is like a straight line?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory, lattice-orders, extremal-combinatorics

Given some pairwise relations:

[image: Relations]

The Hasse diagram I drew looked like:
$$3\to13\to23\to123\to12\to1\to2$$
What does it mean when it is a straight line? Is there any theorem that infers something based on the fact that the result is a linear Hasse diagram?

Comment: It means that the partial order is a linear order, also called a total order.

Comment: In that case, if a function $f$ defined such that $f(A,B)$ is defined $\forall A,B \subseteq 2^E$ have pairwise relations that form a total order as you put it, then does it mean that $f(.)$ can be optimized to obtain it's maxima or minima using the least number of steps possible relative to number of steps required by set functions that do not form this total order? Is there any theory that guarantees that with or without additional assumptions about the set function $f(,)$?

Answer (score 3):

It means your order is a .... wait for it.... linear order ( Ba Dum Tsss)

Comment: In that case, if a function $f$ defined such that $f(A,B)$ is defined $\forall A,B \subseteq 2^E$ have pairwise relations that form a total order as you put it, then does it mean that $f(.)$ can be optimized to obtain it's maxima or minima using the least number of steps possible relative to functions that do not form this total order?Is there any theory that guarantees that with or without additional assumptions about the set function $f(,)$?

Answer (score 2):

When the Hasse diagram looks like a line, that means the relation described defines a *total order* on the set. In other words, every two elements in the set may be compared.

Comment: In that case, if a function $f$ defined such that $f(A,B)$ is defined $\forall A,B \subseteq 2^E$ have pairwise relations that form a total order as you put it, then does it mean that $f(.)$ can be optimized to obtain it's maxima or minima using the least number of steps possible relative to functions that do not form this total order?Is there any theory that guarantees that with or without additional assumptions about the set function $f(,)$?

Comment: @user251385 As I can understand it, if $f$ is a total order on $2^E$, you can rearrange the elements of $2^E$ such that there is a "greatest element" and "smallest element". Then the minimum and maximum of $f$ are attained when these extremal elements are the arguments to $f$.

Comment: My question was on whether the total order guarantees that it requires the "least number of function evaluations" vs a function that has a partial order or say forms a greedoid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedoid if  were to be maximized or minimized ? Note, if cardinality of $E$ is large evaluating all possible values of $f$ is gonna be very hard. Hence, I ask wrt linear order providing faster algorithms or mathematical techniques to do combinatorial optimization of $f$?

Comment: @user251385 The function $f$ on pairs of elements in $2^E$ may not be related to the total order at all. It is up to the function's properties to determine whether or not finding the extrema can be done in a faster way. For example, if $f$ is defined as the "signed distance from first argument to second argument" (e.g. with your example, $f(12,23)=-2$), minima and maxima of $f$ are $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$. If it is defined in a more complicated way, there may not be a simpler approach than just trying everything out.